# AWS Ubuntu 18.04 Change Nameserver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04

How can I change the DNS nameserver for a Ubuntu instance on AWS?

When I edit `/etc/network/interfaces` it tells me to check `/etc/netplan`.
That says that changes will not persist across an instance.

How do I change the nameserver?

Comment: IIRC there is a symbolic link at `/etc/resolv.conf` - remove it, and recreate it as a file with a proper entry.

Comment: I wonder if you could use a [DHCP Option Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html)